# Android - findViewById() vs findViewWithTag()

Tags: java, android

When writing a large application having many views (and as a result, many ids),
which is a better practice or is better performance-wise; 
Having many ids and finding them with `findViewById(X)`, 
Or having multiple tags and finding the views using `findViewWithTag(Y)`?

Comment: I'd love to know why I was down-voted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as better practice is concerned, use one or both (typically both) depending on the requirements of the application. If I were you I would care more for the usability and grouping than performance (since the application is large and may become unmaintainable).

Acc. to this part of Android Docs :

### Tags Unlike IDs, tags are not used to identify views. Tags are essentially an extra piece of information that can be associated with a view. They are most often used as a convenience to store data related to views in the views themselves rather than by putting them in a separate structure.

The primary purpose of Tag in Android is to make grouping of code cleaner. Think of it as marking items in a supermarket with categories: Food, Electronics etc... I think using tags will have very minimal impact on performance at best.

The practices described below, though,  will have a lot more impact on performance than avoiding using tags/views or both.

If you want to improve performance,

- Keep the branching of layout elements to a minimum
  https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html
- Create layouts and reuse them in multiple places
  https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html
- Load views when required (also called [Lazy Loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading))
  https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/loading-ondemand.html
- [Other Performance Tips](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html)

Answer (score 1):

`findViewWithTag()` is only defined for a View. However, `findViewById()` is usable for View and Activity.

I believe that `findViewById()` best practices to accessing views. Even you should use Butterknife http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ for accessing views.

Performance: `findViewById()` is faster than `findViewWithTag()` because comparing **int** faster than **String.equals()**.

**View.java**

```
protected View findViewTraversal(@IdRes int id) {
    if (id == mID) {
        return this;
    }
    return null;
}

protected View findViewWithTagTraversal(Object tag) {
    if (tag != null && tag.equals(mTag)) {
        return this;
    }
    return null;
}
```