# Should i use findbyTag() when i have too many layouts?

Tags: java, android

I am using findViewWithTag insted of findViewById because i have a button in matrix of 5*5 and i dont want to write findVieById everytime , so i took tag string and initialized the layout with findByViewTag is this the correct? If not please suggest
eg:-

```
android:tag="gridImage29" in below Imageview
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp1"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="#415667"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp14"
        android:tag="gridImage29" />
```

Comment: use `GridView` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It will work. Generally, it is used for view created dynamically.

Comment: is butterknife better solution then this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use but it is typical to use `findViewWithTag` instead of `findViewById`. [Please refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39999480/2264534)

Comment: Please write reference link in comment section instead of post answer.

Comment: @InsaneCat Why? this is actually a valid answer.

Comment: Did you post a link as a answer too @KlingKlang huh?

Comment: @InsaneCat It's not actually a link-only answer. Read well. There's (a very compact sort of) an answer.